# Android wear not uploading data to Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, wear-os

Instead of using the Data Layer and sending the data to phone, and uploading it from there, I simply wrote this code under a button:

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://poponfa-8a11a.firebaseio.com/");
ref.child("lol").setValue("lol");
```

But for some strange reason, it usually suddenly stops working, pressing the button uploads nothing to firebase even though the phone is connected to the watch and internet. My question is, why is this behaviour occurring and how do I go about uploading directly from Wear, as I don't want to keep services running in the mobile App.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried this personally, but you may want to try [Identifying your Wear app as standalone](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/standalone-apps.html).

Add the following in your Android Manifest file:

```
<application>
...
  <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.wearable.standalone"
    android:value="true" />
...
</application>
```

With this, a watch app can be considered as one of the following:

> - Completely independent of a phone app
> - Semi-independent (a phone app is not required and would provide only
>     optional features)
> - Dependent on a phone app

Then, you can proceed with saving data directly from your Wear.

See [Read and Write Data on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write) for more information.

Comment: It didn't work. The thing is, the uploading of data is inconsistent, at times it uploads and at times it doesn't. Irrespective of the internet connections of the phone and wearable.